# PDO can connect to MySQL in localhost, but not remote, even they are the same server

Tags: php, mysql, connection, pdo

Let's say the MySQL server is `mydomain.com:3306`, and the Apache and MySQL are on the same server machine.

When I upload my PHP script to the server, I can always connect the MySQL with PDO and this DNS:

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database
```

However, if I change the DNS string to this:

```
mysql:host=mydomain.com;dbname=my_database
```

Just changed `localhost` to `mydomain.com`, all others settings like username and password remain the same. I got this warning:

```
OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected
```

I found many discussions about the `OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected` problem and they are all related to the password hashing. However, since I can connect to the server using the `localhost` setting, I don't think in my case the password hashing is the reason.

Any one got this problem?

p.s. I'm using Kohana 3.0.9's database module to do the connection.
p.p.s. MySQL version: 5.1.52, PHP version: 5.3.2

Comment: only this warning? or also 'mysqlnd cannot connect to
MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication'? The password hashing can be the reason if you have another user for 'user'@'mydomain.com'

Comment: yes. only this error. there is no other error message shown. actually i can connect to the remote server with a GUI tool (SQLyog) using the domain name. It just doesn't work with my PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because `127.0.0.1:3306` is a different IP & port from `yourExternalIP:3306` and using your domain name will connect with your *external IP* which will not be the same IP as `localhost` (127.0.0.1)

Unless you have configured mysql to listen on *all* IPs, and to allow access for all users *from* all IPs you cannot assume mysql is listening on your external IP, or that the username/password is allowed to access from a "remote host" (i.e. from & through your external IP)

Comment: Remote access to MySQL is allowed (only limited to certain IPs).
I can connect the remote server with SQLyog (a mySQL GUI management tool), using the domain name as the host.

Comment: @LazNiko: omg, don't you see the difference between connect from local to remote and connect from anywhere to local?

Comment: @zerkms: since my server is on linux, i can't use SQLyog to connect the server with "localhost" setting. I'm using SQLyog on a winXP pc to connect to the server, using the domain name as the host. SQLyog works fine and no error/warning reported during the connection. I can do C/R/U/D operations on the remote server as well.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's drivers have an "optimization", where using "localhost" as your server hostname will internally be remapped into using unix-domain sockets instead of TCP sockets. This is for speed reasons, as unix sockets are much faster than TCP (especially since you don't have the overhead of a full run through the TCP stack), but it does lead to inconsistent behavior as you're seeing, especially when using mismatched driver versions.

Answer (score 0):

Can mysql client connect using hostname?

- It is possible that mysql doesn't listen the interface resolved by DNS.
- Or even mysql can be configured with network connection being turned off, but you can connect locally through socket.

Comment: I can connect the remote server with SQLyog (a mySQL GUI management tool), using the domain name as the host.

Comment: @LazNiko: because remote host allowed remote connections. That is why I wrote to possibilities why you cannot connect to the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting company uses SAT for their servers, meaning that you server has an internal IP (for example: 10.0.0.101), and address translate the external IP that you resolve using mydomain.com (example: 241.34.31.2), then their firewall might not be setup to actually route that kind of traffic back in again.

Either way, it's not a good idea to force all traffic through the firewall in that case, and you would be better off using your IP directly (or localhost).

But I'm guessing the other suggestions here are more plausible, especially if the error is related to password-checking.